# Migrate grunt to webpack

Tags: css, webpack, sass, gruntjs, sprite

I have a project that uses grunt to manage all my static files (compress files, generate sprites through the compass and etc). I started the migration and I am stuck on the issue of not being able to include all my icons and call them through the functions of the compass.

My main.scss file has the following lines:

```
@import "icons";
@include all-icons-sprites;

@include icons-sprite(icon-arrow);
```

But this give me an error:

*Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):    @import "icons";
^*

How can I make it work?

Comment: is icons, named _icons?

Comment: yes!
I following this http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/

Comment: You need to include the path to the icons relative to the `.scss' file. Is it in the same place or in a sub folder?